# Is there a way to get sha1 fingerprint and/or package name to send it via API in runtime?

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

What I need to know is a way to get SHA1 fingerprint and package name to autenticate an user via API, like this:

`

```
void main(){
  
postMethod(Uri url, {required Map<String, dynamic> header}){}  
getAppSha1Fingerprint(){}
  
  
    var sha1 = getAppSha1Fingerprint();
    var response = postMethod(
        Uri.parse('some url'),
        header: {
           'sha1': sha1
        },
    );
}
```

`

I'm not pretending to get sha1 fingerprint via console to save it in Firebase. I want to know how firebase receives the sha1 when an app make a request from his API.

ps: I've found this turorial on how to do this in java. I'm not experienced in java programming and in making Method Channel things but if there is no code in dart then I'll be veeery happy in try:

[tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589308/how-does-google-verify-android-sha1-fingerprints-and-packages)

Thank You!

I tried to search for it but the only thing I got was how to get sha1 fingerprint BEFORE app compile

Answer (score 0):

For the package name, you can use the below plugin.

https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus

About the **sha1** key, I think you can try to add your certificate file in the **app_name/assets/** folder, and then load the file using **AssetBundle** class.

Official Documentation - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html

Good example of loading **JSON** file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005064/11943995

Comment: for the sha1, sadly, if I keep it in a constant, anyone could replicate the app and get access to my api...